# how do you pass a image file to ashx also give a error Could not create type 'uploader'

Tags: c#, asp.net, ashx

I have an aspx page which has an iframe inside that iframe i have an ascx page

code example

```
<form action="uploader.ashx" id="frmUploadPhoto" runat="server" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <div  style="height: 80px;"></div>
        <div >
            <asp:fileupload runat="server" cssclass="btnSml" id="uploadPhoto" width="155px" />            
            <asp:button runat="server" cssclass="btnSml" id="btnUploadPhoto" text="Upload" />

        </div>
    </form>
```

my question is, how do i pass the data to an ashx control so i can save the file?

```
public class UploadHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public class Upload : IHttpHandler {
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {         
     HttpPostedFile oFile = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];
     string sDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("uploads");
     oFile.SaveAs(sDirectory + oFile.FileName);     
   }
   public bool IsReusable {
      get { return false; }
   }
}


}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should already be passing it since you've placed the ashx handler as your form's target. Are you getting errors or something?

Comment: getting this error Could not create type 'uploader'.
at System.Web.UI.SimpleWebHandlerParser.GetType(String typeName)
at System.Web.UI.SimpleWebHandlerParser.GetTypeToCache(Assembly builtAssembly)
at System.Web.Compilation.SimpleHandlerBuildProvider.GetGeneratedType(CompilerResults results)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.CreateBuildResult(CompilerResults results)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetBuildResult(CompilerResults results)
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)

Comment: Post the error and the code for uploader.ashx in the question

Comment: Do you have an actual .ashx file? What kind of project are you using? Web Application?